# Jquery UI Sortable + Toggle Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to implement a simple connected sortable whose `display` can be toggled by the user.

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#content').toggle();
});

$('#target').sortable();
$('#source div').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#target',
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

I'm running into an issue here. If the sortable (target) is collapsed, and a drag operation is performed, the sortable stops working.

See http://jsfiddle.net/9hGrs/12/

1. Click on the toggle button to hide the sortable
2. Drag any item from the source to anywhere on the page, and release it (i.e. this simulates an invalid drop)
3. Click on the toggle button again to show the sortable
4. Now, when you try to drag/drop an item from the source into the sortable, it doesn't accept the draggable.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly I have got it to only fail on the item that was the invalid drop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the invalid option, and disable and enable the target when you hide:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    if($('#content').is(":visible")) {
      $( "#target" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", true );
      $("#content").hide();
} else {
      $( "#target" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", false );
      $("#content").show();            
    }

});

$('#target').sortable();
$('#source div').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#target',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

[A modified JSFiddle showing this working](http://jsfiddle.net/TjNfD/).

Answer (score 2):

This problem doesn't occur with jquery 1.6.1 / jquery-ui 1.8.14.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hGrs/16/